# Antlr: Unintended behavior

Tags: antlr

Why this simple grammar

```
grammar Test;

expr
    :    Int | expr '+' expr;

Int
:    [0-9]+;
```

doesn't match the input `1+1` ? It says "No method for rule expr or it has arguments" but in my opition it should be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I haven't used ANTLR for a while... ANTLRv3 *did not* support left-recursive rules, [but ANTLRv4 does support immediate left recursion](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29130850). It also supports the regex-like character class syntax you used in your post. I tested this version and it works in ANTLRWorks2 (running on ANTLR4):

```
grammar Test;

start : expr
      ;
expr  : expr '+' expr
      | INT
      ;
INT   : [0-9]+
      ;
```

If you add the `start` rule then ANTLR is able to infer that `EOF` goes at the end of that rule. It doesn't seem to be able to infer `EOF` for more complex rules like `expr` and `expr2` since they're recursive...

---

There are a lot of comments below, so here is (co-author of ANTLR4) Sam Harwell's response (emphasis added):

> You still want to include an explicit EOF in the start rule. The problem the OP faced with using expr directly is **ANTLR 4 internally rewrote it to be expr[int _p]** (it does so for all left recursive rules), and the included **TestRig is not able to directly execute rules with parameters**. Adding a start rule resolves the problem because TestRig is able to execute that rule. :)

I've posted a follow-up question with regard to `EOF`: [When is EOF needed in ANTLR 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844248/when-is-eof-needed-in-antlr-4)

Comment: But why didn't compiler marked as an error and why [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) on line 509 `expression` is defined as left-recursive and it doesn't seem to be a problem

Comment: @IvanPetkov - There were more problems than I thought. I've edited my answer and tested the grammar in ANTLRWorks. It works now.

Comment: Thanks, now's a little bit clearer but about [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4). `expression` is defined as left-recursive.

Comment: @IvanPetkov - I did a bit of research, and it looks like they added support for _direct_ left recursion in ANTLRv4. I added a link in my answer to a page on the ANTLR website that discusses this change.

Comment: And still I can't answer my first question. Why `1+1` is not being matched? Does not make sense.

Comment: @IvanPetkov - OK, tested again and now it actually parses `1+1`. Lack of an `EOF` was making it not accept the whole input before.

Comment: You mean  that after changing the rule to `expr: INT | expr '+' expr EOF;` it should be fine?

Comment: @IvanPetkov - Yes, I think that would work if you want to match `1+1`, but not for `1+2+3`. I've updated my answer again with a left-recursive version I tested in ANTLRWorks2 (I was using 1.5 before).

Comment: Ok, and why if we have only the rules `expr: INT | expr '+' expr EOF; INT: '0'..'9'+;` `1+1` is not being matched?

Comment: @IvanPetkov - I have no idea... `expr : INT '+' expr | INT ;
INT : [0-9]+;` Also seems to work—but that still doesn't answer your question.

Comment: You still want to include an explicit `EOF` in the `start` rule. The problem the OP faced with using `expr` directly is ANTLR 4 internally rewrote it to be `expr[int _p]` (it does so for all left recursive rules), and the included TestRig is not able to directly execute rules with parameters. Adding a `start` rule resolves the problem because TestRig is able to execute that rule. :)

Comment: I deleted the first half of this answer because it was almost entirely incorrect, and the parts which were correct weren't relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Also, `Int` and `INT` are equally valid as lexer rules in ANTLR (versions 3 and 4). The only reason to favor the form `INT` is it produces constants in code which follow Java conventions for constants (all caps).

Comment: @280Z28 - Thanks for the edits. I'm glad one of the authors came along to clarify this, because as you pointed out my initial answer was all ANTLR3-specific and not really applicable. I'm still confused about `EOF` though, so I posted [a separate question on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844248/when-is-eof-needed-in-antlr-4).

Answer (score 1):

If your command looks like this:

```
grun MYGRAMMAR xxx -tokens
```

And this exception is thrown:

```
No method for rule xxx or it has arguments
```

Then this exception will get thrown with the rule you specified in the command above.  It means the rule probably doesn't exist.

```
System.err.println("No method for rule "+startRuleName+" or it has arguments");
```

So `startRuleName` here, should print `xxx` if it's not the first (start) rule in the grammar.  Put `xxx` as the first rule in your grammar to prevent this.