# When is EOF needed in ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

The *TestDriver* in ANTLRWorks2 seems kind of finicky about when it'll accept a grammer without and explicit `EOF` and when it will not. The *Hello* grammar in the [ANTLR4 Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) doesn't use `EOF` anywhere, so I inferred that it's better to avoid explicit `EOF` if possible.

What is the best practice for using `EOF`? When do you actually need it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should include an explicit `EOF` at the end of your entry rule any time you are trying to parse an entire input file. If you do not include the `EOF`, it means you are not trying to parse the entire input, and it's acceptable to parse only a portion of the input if it means avoiding a syntax error.

For example, consider the following rule:

```
file : item*;
```

This rule means "Parse as many `item` elements as possible, and then stop." In other words, this rule will *never* attempt to recover from a syntax error because it will *always* assume that the syntax error is part of some syntactic construct that's beyond the scope of the `file` rule. Syntax errors will not even be reported, because the parser will simply stop.

If instead I had the following rule:

```
file : item* EOF;
```

In means "A file consists exactly of a sequence of zero-or-more `item` elements." If a syntax error is reached while parsing an `item` element, this rule *will* attempt to recover from (and report) the syntax error and continue because the `EOF` is required and has not yet been reached.

---

For rules where you are only trying to parse a portion of the input, ANTLR 4 often works, but not always. The following issue describes a technical problem where ANTLR 4 does not always make the correct decision if the `EOF` is omitted.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/118

Unfortunately the performance impact of this change is *substantial*, so until that is resolved there will be edge cases that do not behave as you expect.

Comment: Stumbled upon this while searching for why antlr4 silently ignores tokens at the end of the input file. Thanks Sam!

Comment: Precisely the same situation here, five years later! :)