# Antlr4 parsing issue

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr4, lexer

When I try to work my message.expr file with Zmes.g4 grammar file via antlr-4.7.1-complete only first line works and there is no reaction for second one. Grammar is

```
grammar Zmes;
prog    :   stat+;
stat    :  (message|define);
message :  'MSG'     MSGNUM    TEXT; 
define  :  'DEF:'  ('String '|'int ')  ID ( ','  ('String '|'Int ')  ID)* ';';
fragment QUOTE      :   '\'';
MSGNUM              :   [0-9]+; 
TEXT                :   QUOTE ~[']* QUOTE;
MODULE              :   [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] ;
ID                  :   [A-Z]([A-Za-z0-9_])*;
SKIPS               :   (' '|'\t'|'\r'?'\n'|'\r')+ -> skip;
```

and message.expr is

```
MSG 100  'MESSAGE YU';
DEF: String Svar1,Int Intv1;`
```

On cmd when I run like this

```
grun Zmes prog -tree message.expr
```

> (prog (stat (message MSG 100 'MESSAGE YU')))
>   and there is no second reaction. Why can it be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `message` should include `';'` at the end:

```
message :  'MSG'     MSGNUM    TEXT ';';
```

Also, in your `define` rule you have `'int '`, which should probably be `'Int'` (no space and a capital `i`).

I'd go for something like this:

```
grammar Zmes;

prog    : stat+ EOF;
stat    : (message | define) SCOL;
message : MSG MSGNUM TEXT;
define  : DEF COL type ID (COMMA type ID)*;
type    : STRING | INT;

MSG    : 'MSG';
DEF    : 'DEF';
STRING : 'String';
INT    : 'Int';
COL    : ':';
SCOL   : ';';
COMMA  : ',';
MSGNUM : [0-9]+;
TEXT   : '\'' ~[']* '\'';
MODULE : [A-Z] [A-Z] [A-Z] ;
ID     : [A-Z] [A-Za-z0-9_]*;
SKIPS  : (' '|'\t'|'\r'?'\n'|'\r')+ -> skip;
```

which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should also add EOF if you want to parse the entire input, e.g.

```
prog    :   stat+ EOF;
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844248/when-is-eof-needed-in-antlr-4) why.